# ollydbg: CMP - what the difference

Tags: ollydbg

What is the difference between:

```
MOV SI,WORD PTR DS:[ESI+0D]

CMP SI,1388
```

and

```
CMP WORD PTR DS:[ESI+0d],1388
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are the same for the given assembly snippet, but in the first snippet, the value of `ESI+0D` is saved in `SI` and could be later used again without loading it from the memory additional time.

Comment: also think so, but because i am very new to ollydbg i asked it here, because SI never used any futher down the code, so i wondered why developers (i am editing game 1998 year) choose to save value in SI rather than use straight compare.

Comment: I believe it was the compiler's choice and the developer's choice.